# datos de un gridview a edittexts

Tags: android, gridview, edittext

Tengo un gridview con 6 columnas.
Pretendo pasar los datos de una fila al tocar un ítem de la misma.
Es decir, que al tocar un ítem coja toda la fila y la pase a 6 edit text.

Comment: Y ¿Cuál es la pregunta? edita tu pregunta, agrega lo que llevas hecho y explica mejor :)

Comment: juanjo, Bienvenido al sitio. Por favor incluye al menos un ejemplo de lo que has intentado y lo que pretendes lograr para poder ayudarte.